# How to hide certain DIV from Google bot and other bots

Tags: html, seo

so I have a website that requires the user to verify its age before they can see any information, I display the option to select if you are older than 18 years old with a DIV:

```
<div class="ct-preloader">
  <div class="contenido-edad">
    <div class="ct-mediaSection-inner ct-u-paddingTop100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h4 class="text-center"><small>VNO es una aplicación para mayores de edad, al entrar aceptas nuestros términos y condiciones.</small></h4>
            <h2 class="text-center ct-u-marginTop0"><small class="text-uppercase ct-u-cabin ct-u-ls-10 ct-u-ls--xs0">¿Eres mayor de edad? (+18)</small></h2>
            <div class="text-center">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default boton-si"><span> Sí </span></a>
              <a href="http://omfgdogs.com" class="btn btn-default boton-no"><span> No </span></a><br><br><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="si" id="recordarPreferencia"> ¿Recordar preferencia?
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I make it apear in the whole webpage with this CSS:

```
.ct-preloader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99998;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the problem is that I think this is making my ranking on Google go down, because that is what the Google bot sees, so I would like to know if there is a way to hide this whole div from Google and other bots, the website I'm talking about is https://vno.mx

Answer (score 0):

The best way to suggest that a webcrawler not access content on your site is to create a robots.txt file. See http://robotstxt.org. There is no way to tell a robot to not access one part of a page

http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/faq.html#h22

If you are going to use CSS remember that robots can still read CSS files! You could include the CSS file in the robots.txt file, though to exclude it.

If you really must have indexed and non-indexed content on the same page, maybe you should use frames and have the non-indexed frame listed in the robots.txt file as not to be indexed.

Well behaved crawlers will follow the robots.txt guidance, e.g. Google, but naughty ones will not. So, there is no guarantee.

Comment: you know that your answere has non to do with the actual question, dont you ? :D